# how to slow setinterval rectangle respawn

Tags: javascript, canvas

so i try to make snake game using javascript canvas, and i try to make food to keep respawning using setInterval, but when i do that the food it just keep respawning fastly, is there any way to slow it down?, im sorry for my bad english

```js
    const c = document.getElementById("canvas")
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d")

    c.width = 400
    c.height = 400

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {

        class board {
            constructor(game) {
                this.game = game
                this.x = 0
                this.y = 0
                this.width = 160
                this.height = 20
                this.delta = this.width / 8
                this.light = "rgba(20,58,81,255)"
                this.dark = "rgba(27,77,105,255)"
            }

            draw(ctx) {
                for(let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                    for(let j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                        ctx.fillStyle = (i + j) % 2 === 0 ? this.light : this.dark
                        ctx.fillRect(this.x + this.delta * (i - 1), this.y + this.delta * (j - 1), this.delta, this.delta )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        class snake {
            constructor(game) {
                this.game = game
                this.col = 'rgba(122,96,46,255)'
                this.border = 'white'
                this.width = 20
                this.height = 20
                this.sx = 20
                this.sy = 0
                this.snakePart =  [
                    {x : 100, y : 100},
                    {x : 80, y : 100},
                    {x : 60, y : 100},
                    {x : 40, y : 100},
                    {x : 20, y : 100},
                    {x : 0, y : 100}
                ]

            }    

            update() {
                this.snakePart.unshift
                ({
                    x : this.snakePart[0].x + this.sx,
                    y : this.snakePart[0].y + this.sy
                })

                window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
                    switch(e.key) {
                        case "w":
                            this.sy = -20
                            this.sx = 0
                        break
                        case "s":
                            this.sy = 20
                            this.sx = 0
                        break
                        case "a":
                            this.sx = -20
                            this.sy = 0
                        break
                        case "d":
                            this.sx = 20
                            this.sy = 0
                    }
                })
                this.snakePart.pop()
               
            }
            draw(ctx) {
                this.snakePart.forEach(s => {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = this.border
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.col
                    ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y, this.width, this.height)
                    ctx.strokeRect(s.x, s.y , this.width, this.height)
                    ctx.closePath()
                })
            }

           
        }
        class food {
            constructor(game) {
                this.game = game
                this.width = 20
                this.height = 20
            }

            draw(ctx) {
                setInterval(() => {
                   for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
                    ctx.fillRect(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * i,Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * i, this.width, this.height)
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }

       
        class game {
            constructor() {
                this.board = new board(this)
                this.snake = new snake(this)
                this.food = new food(this)
            }

            draw(ctx) {
                this.board.draw(ctx)
                this.snake.draw(ctx)
                this.food.draw(ctx)
            }
            
            update(ctx) {
                
                this.snake.update(ctx)
            }

            clearCanvas(ctx) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "white"
                ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
                ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
            }
        }

        const games = new game

        function play() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                games.clearCanvas(ctx)
                games.draw(ctx)
                games.update(ctx)
                play()
            }, 100)

        }
        play()
    })
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
```

> This is the food class, i make the setInterval inside draw method

```
 class food {
            constructor(game) {
                this.game = game
                this.width = 20
                this.height = 20
            }

            draw(ctx) {
                setInterval(() => {
                   for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
                    ctx.fillRect(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * i,Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * i, this.width, this.height)
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Every time you run `this.food.draw` you create a new interval so I guess after some time there are thousand of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple intervals that is not a problem but you have to be careful not to have them nested, like Konrad pointed in the comments:

> Every time you run `this.food.draw` you create a new interval
> so I guess after some time there are thousand of them.

That will be bad, and the outcome is exactly what you experienced, they keep respawning faster and faster.

Below I refactored your code to separate the drawing and the respawning of new food, that way we can have two intervals, one that draws and update everything, the second that creates new food.

```js
const c = document.getElementById("canvas")
const ctx = c.getContext("2d")

class board {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 0
    this.y = 0
    this.width = 160
    this.height = 20
    this.delta = this.width / 8
    this.light = "rgba(20,58,81,255)"
    this.dark = "rgba(27,77,105,255)"
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = (i + j) % 2 === 0 ? this.light : this.dark
        ctx.fillRect(this.x + this.delta * (i - 1), this.y + this.delta * (j - 1), this.delta, this.delta)
      }
    }
  }
}

class snake {
  constructor() {
    this.col = 'rgba(122,96,46,255)'
    this.border = 'white'
    this.width = 20
    this.height = 20
    this.sx = 20
    this.sy = 0
    this.snakePart = [{ x: 100, y: 100 }, { x: 80, y: 100 }, { x: 60, y: 100 }, { x: 40, y: 100 }, { x: 20, y: 100 }, { x: 0, y: 100 } ]
  }

  update() {
    this.snakePart.unshift({
      x: this.snakePart[0].x + this.sx,
      y: this.snakePart[0].y + this.sy
    })

    window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
      switch (e.key) {
        case "w":
          this.sy = -20
          this.sx = 0
          break
        case "s":
          this.sy = 20
          this.sx = 0
          break
        case "a":
          this.sx = -20
          this.sy = 0
          break
        case "d":
          this.sx = 20
          this.sy = 0
      }
    })
    this.snakePart.pop()

  }
  draw(ctx) {
    this.snakePart.forEach(s => {
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.border
      ctx.fillStyle = this.col
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y, this.width, this.height)
      ctx.strokeRect(s.x, s.y, this.width, this.height)
      ctx.closePath()
    })
  }
}

class food {
  constructor() {
    this.width = 20
    this.height = 20
    this.newFood()
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
      ctx.fillRect(this.items[i][0], this.items[i][1], this.width, this.height)
    }
  }

  newFood() {
    this.items = []
    this.items.push([Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)])
    this.items.push([Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)])
  }
}

class game {
  constructor() {
    this.board = new board(this)
    this.snake = new snake(this)
    this.food = new food()
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    this.board.draw(ctx)
    this.snake.draw(ctx)
    this.food.draw(ctx)
  }

  update(ctx) {
    this.snake.update(ctx)
  }
  
  newFood() {
    this.food.newFood()
  }

  clearCanvas(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const games = new game
  setInterval(() => {
    games.clearCanvas(ctx)
    games.draw(ctx)
    games.update(ctx)
  }, 100)
  
  setInterval(() => {
    games.newFood(ctx)
  }, 1000)
  
  const keys = ["s","a","w","d"]
  var key = 0
  setInterval(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':keys[key++%4]}));
  }, 455)
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

I added a 3rd interval that dispatches some events to make the snake move automatically

Answer (score -2):

try this insted :

```
 const  c = document.getElementById("canvas")
        console.log(c)
        ctx = c.getContext("2d")
        

        c.width = 400
        c.height = 400
    
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    
            class board {
                constructor(game) {
                    this.game = game
                    this.x = 0
                    this.y = 0
                    this.width = 160
                    this.height = 20
                    this.delta = this.width / 8
                    this.light = "rgba(20,58,81,255)"
                    this.dark = "rgba(27,77,105,255)"
                }
    
                draw(ctx) {
                    for(let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                        for(let j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                            ctx.fillStyle = (i + j) % 2 === 0 ? this.light : this.dark
                            ctx.fillRect(this.x + this.delta * (i - 1), this.y + this.delta * (j - 1), this.delta, this.delta )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            class snake {
                constructor(game) {
                    this.game = game
                    this.col = 'rgba(122,96,46,255)'
                    this.border = 'white'
                    this.width = 20
                    this.height = 20
                    this.sx = 20
                    this.sy = 0
                    this.snakePart =  [
                        {x : 100, y : 100},
                        {x : 80, y : 100},
                        {x : 60, y : 100},
                        {x : 40, y : 100},
                        {x : 20, y : 100},
                        {x : 0, y : 100}
                    ]
    
                }    
    
                update() {
                    this.snakePart.unshift
                    ({
                        x : this.snakePart[0].x + this.sx,
                        y : this.snakePart[0].y + this.sy
                    })
    
                    window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
                        switch(e.key) {
                            case "w":
                                this.sy = -20
                                this.sx = 0
                            break
                            case "s":
                                this.sy = 20
                                this.sx = 0
                            break
                            case "a":
                                this.sx = -20
                                this.sy = 0
                            break
                            case "d":
                                this.sx = 20
                                this.sy = 0
                        }
                    })
                    this.snakePart.pop()
                   
                }
                draw(ctx) {
                    this.snakePart.forEach(s => {
                        ctx.strokeStyle = this.border
                        ctx.fillStyle = this.col
                        ctx.beginPath()
                        ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y, this.width, this.height)
                        ctx.strokeRect(s.x, s.y , this.width, this.height)
                        ctx.closePath()
                    })
                }
    
               
            }
            class food {
                constructor(game) {
                    this.game = game
                    this.width = 20
                    this.height = 20
                }
    
                draw(ctx) {
               
                       for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
                        ctx.fillRect(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * i,Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * i, this.width, this.height)
                    }
                
            }
        }
    
           
            class game {
                constructor() {
                    this.board = new board(this)
                    this.snake = new snake(this)
                    this.food = new food(this)
                }
    
                draw(ctx) {
                    this.board.draw(ctx)
                    this.snake.draw(ctx)
                    this.food.draw(ctx)                        
                }
                
                update(ctx) {
                    
                    this.snake.update(ctx)
                }
    
                clearCanvas(ctx) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
                    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
                }
            }
    
            const games = new game

            function play() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    games.clearCanvas(ctx)
                    games.draw(ctx)
                    games.update(ctx)
                    play()
                }, 300)
            }
            play()
        })
```

Comment: it works, the food not respawning fastly, but when i delete the play() inside the function, the snake not working

Comment: try to apply changes , seem's the problem whas the set interval inside the food draw

Comment: sorry for asking to much, but it just same https://jsfiddle.net/rgnkfvsz/1/

Comment: for me snake is working and respawn of food is slow down in your sandbox if you wanna make it slower just make setTimeout greater